# cfoutput grouped query - seeing the result

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'd like to have a look at the query that would be inside this:

```
<cfoutput query="myQuery" group="ID">
   <cfdump var="#theResultingRows#" />
</cfoutput>
```

Is there a way of getting the internal query results other than running a QoQ with matching id?

Comment: If you mean, "can I dump the results of this group of records", I don't think there's built-in reference for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use nested cfoutput tags as described in the documentation.  You can also use a loop and array notation to save typing.

```
<cfoutput query="x" group="id">
 id is #id#<hr>
 <cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#x.columnlist#" index="field">
      #field# is #x[field][currentrow]#
    </cfloop>
    <br>
  </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```